# Can´t trigger a javaScript method on the onload event of a form

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am trying to call a JavaScript method on the onload() event of a form. Here is the code for the javaScript:

```
<script type="text/javascript">  
    function gback(){
                document.FM.action = "<c:url value='FModificar'/>";
                document.FM.method = "get";
                document.FM.submit();
              } 

               function DelF() {
                        jConfirm('Can you confirm this?', 'Confirmation Dialog', function(r) {

                                 if (r == true) {
                                     $("form[name='FEl']").submit();

                                    } else {
                                      return false;
                                    }
                        });
                    }

               function Check(msg){
                   if(msg.toString().length > 5){                 
                     jAlert('success', msg, 'Success');

                   }
               }

</script>
```

And here is the html code:

```
 <%-- FornecedorList is requested --%>
                        <c:if test="${!empty VFornecedorList}">

                            <table id="ProductTable" class="detailsTable" onload="Check(${CFP})">

                                    <tr class="header">
                                        <th colspan="7" >Fornecedor</th>
                                    </tr>

                                    <tr class="tableHeading">
                                        <td>ID</td>
                                        <td>Nome</td>
                                        <td>Endereço</td>
                                        <td>Descrição</td>
                                        <td>Nº de Celulare</td>
                                        <td>Nº de Telefone</td>
                                        <td>Email</td>    
                                        <td>Fax</td> 

                                    </tr>

                                    <c:forEach var="VForn" items="${VFornecedorList}" varStatus="iter">

                                        <tr class="${'white'} tableRow">   
                                            <td>${VForn.getFid()}</td>
                                            <td>${VForn.getFNome()}</td>
                                            <td>${VForn.getFEndereco()}</td>
                                            <td>${VForn.getFDescricao()}</td>
                                            <td>${VForn.getFNCel()}</td>
                                            <td>${VForn.getFNTel()}</td>
                                            <td>${VForn.getFEmail()}</td>    
                                            <td>${VForn.getFFax()}</td> 
                                        </tr>

                                    </c:forEach>

                                </table>

                            </c:if> 
                    <%-- END FornecedorList is requested --%>
```

Also the method receives a parameter from the controller. Here is the code:

```
//Add a Fornecedor
             fornece = transManager.addfornecedor(ID, nome, endereço, email, cell, tel, fax, des, Fact);
             String Fmsg = "";
             if (!fornece.equals(""))
                   Fmsg = "Fornecedor " + nome + " foi criado"; 

            if(!PFtp.equals("Prodft")){ 
             Fornecedor = transManager.getLEnt("fornecedor");
             request.setAttribute("CFP",Fmsg);
             request.setAttribute("VFornecedorList",Fornecedor);
             userPath = "/Fornecedor";  
            }
```

I am using Netbeans 7.0.1 and Firefox 5. So any advice would be much appreciated.

Comment: Can you explain a little more as to what you are trying to do? Quentin is correct in his answer saying that there is no onload event for a form but from looking at your javascript it doesnt seem like there is anything you would want to run when the page loads. Did you mean when the form is submitted?

Comment: I think i wrote the wrong question its not the on load event of a form but of a table tag.

Answer (score 0):

Forms don't have a load event. A form is just part of a document, not something that loads independently (such as a whole document, or the content or an iframe, or an image).

If you want to run some JS as soon as a form has been parsed, do this:

```
</form>
<script> your js here </script>
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer but i wrote the question for the wrong element its for a table not a form.

Comment: Tables are also just parts of a document. So the answer still applies (just read "table" for "form").